# Laravel add more than 2 parameters in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-controller

In my controller I currently give 2 parameters to the view like this:

```
return view('home')->with(['listings'=>$listings, 'featured_listings'=>$featured_listings]);
```

But when I add a third parameter it gives me the following message:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::index(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

Is there any way to give more than 2 parameters to a view from a controller?

Comment: try my answer and see. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very simple to pass data to view more than one. There are many ways to pass data to view. I suggest you

```
return view('home',compact('listings','featured_listings','your_data',...));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can put parameter like

```
return view('home', [
        'listings' => $listings, 
        'featured_listings' => $featured_listings,
        ..............................
]);
```

then you can put more than 2.

Answer (score 0):

> There are few ways you can share data with a view. It is not limited to 1 or 2 parameters. You can share unlimited parameters.

**Option 1**

```
$categories = ProductCategory::all();
$brands = ProductBrand::all();
$product = Product::first();

return view('product.edit', compact(['categories', 'brands', 'product']));
```

**Option 2**

```
$categories = ProductCategory::all();
$brands = ProductBrand::all();
$product = Product::first();

return view('product.edit', ['categories' => $categories, 'brands' => $brands, 'product' => $product]);
```

**Option 3**

```
$categories = ProductCategory::all();
$brands = ProductBrand::all();
$product = Product::first();

return view('product.edit')->with('categories', $categories)->with('brands', $brands)->with('product', $product);
```